# How do I rearrange two columns in a dataframe so that row values match in R?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I want to sort a 2-column data.frame where column x values are shorter versions of column y values, and such that each column x value matches with only one column y value.

For example, the output should give the "L1" value from column x and the "E17-L1" value from column y on the same row.

Here is what my dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("L1", "L10", "L100", "L101"),
                 y = c("G1-L100", "E17-L1", "E14-L101", "G15-L10"))
df
     x          y
1 L1      G1-L100
2 L10      E17-L1
3 L100   E14-L101
4 L101    G15-L10
```

I need column x to remain in the same order, and column y to be rearranged as is:

```
df
     x          y
1 L1       E17-L1
2 L10     G15-L10
3 L100    G1-L100
4 L101   E14-L101
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to `match` the values in 'x' with that of substring of 'y' by removing the prefix part with `str_remove` and use that index to order the 'y'

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
   mutate(y = y[match(x, str_remove(y, ".*-"))])
#  x        y
#1   L1   E17-L1
#2  L10  G15-L10
#3 L100  G1-L100
#4 L101 E14-L101
```